# execl not running programming

Tags: c++, c, process, exec

I have the following two simple programs:

**bye.cc**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ std::cout <<  "Bye bye bye world" << std::endl; }
```

**hello.cc**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int status;

    cout <<  "Hello world" << endl;

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0) {
        cout << "I am parent - " << pid << endl;
        // wait for child to finish up......
        cout << "Waiting for child to finish" << endl;
        wait(&status);
        cout << "Child finished, status " << status << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "--- I am child - " << pid << endl;   // **Note**
        execl("bye", "");
        cout << "--- I am sleeping" << endl;
        sleep(3);
        exit(11);
    }
}
```

In hello.cc, if the line marked "Note" is enabled (not commented), I get the expected behavior, sleep(3) is not executed, and "bye" is executed, expected msg printed to console.

```
$ ./hello
Hello world
I am parent - 27318
Waiting for child to finish
--- I am child - 0
Bye bye bye world
Child finished, status 0
```

However, when the line marked "Note" is commented, "bye" is NOT executed, and sleep(3) is performed.

```
$ ./hello
Hello world
I am parent - 27350
Waiting for child to finish
--- I am sleeping
Child finished, status 2816
```

Can someone please help me understand what might be going on.  What I found very odd, if I replace the "cout" with a printf(), then the sleep performed.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), the argument list to `execl` must be terminated by a NULL pointer (i.e. `(char *)0`, not `""`).

Changing the nearby code is just changing what happens to be on the stack when you invoke `execl`. As written, the program's behavior is undefined.

P.S. Always check the return value of library routines for errors.

Answer (score 0):

the exec family of functions, when successful, do not return.
That is why you do not see the sleep comment when the execl() is executed.